# How to explicitly compile stack scripts, or cache the compiled object code?

Tags: haskell-stack

I'm currently using a [stack script](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#script-interpreter), and am wondering if this could be sped up by explicitly compiling it to an executable, or alternatively caching the object code so that stack will not recompile every time. Maybe it is already doing the latter - certainly it is for dependencies, just not sure about the object code of the script itself. In which case, I guess I just need to write faster code!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stack exec ghc` to call the ghc installed by stack. Example usage:

```
stack exec ghc --resolver lts-15.0 -- -o test Test.hs
```